# Ubuntu installer/ fdisk/ gpart Can not find my SSD partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, fdisk

I just bought a lenovo flex5 today. Windows 10 was installed on the computer. Trying to make a ubuntu partition for dual boot system.

My process:
-Made a 100GB free partition using windows 10 partition tool. 
-Prepared a ubuntu boot drive

During installation:
The installer didn't find my partition, or any partition for windows 10 system. (only see the windows boot):

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1532116992 bytes, 2992416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.9 GiB, 2003795968 bytes, 3913664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0001746f

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 3913663 3911616  1.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

My computer bios can't see the partition either.
But, the windows 10 is currently using the partition with no problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys. I figured out.....

You will have to go to your computer Bios and switch the booting mode from "Intel RST" mode to "AHCI" mode. After that, you will be able to see all the windows partitions.

Note
Noticing that if your windows was booting using RST mode. Switching to AHCI without safe mode will result in not being able to boot your windows. This will be very troublesome if you plan to make a dual boot system with ubuntu. You will have to switch your windows to boot in AHCI as well. 
Instruction:
https://medium.com/@petragospodneti/windows-10-and-linux-love-hate-dual-boot-problems-d9994cbe16c0

Comment: You wont HAVE a bios if you install ubuntu, because the bios gets corruped if you install ubuntu 17.04. A bug report was filed.

Comment: @TheUbuntuMaster Sorry, I am not a computer expert, but how do you corrupted a computer bios? Computer bios was a chip that is separated from all the other memory, which is the primary owner of THE computer. Also, if the bios die, the whole computer die, is it not?